# Android Architecture Questions

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvvm, architecture, mvp

I've been reading about architecture to android projects. And I found some stuff, but I guess I misunderstood some concepts or not even understood at all.

One of my questions is about handling api objects, if I have a local database, **Should I use the same object from api to store in local database?**

I'm also looking for explanation about why use MVVM or MVP, actually they looks like different stuff, I have figured out that MVP is a pattern more concerned about handling UI responsibilities, MVVM I think is oriented to handle communication between UI and database. **So I misunderstood the concepts or it make sense**?

The last but not least important topic is about dependency injection, I have read about the concept and this question came to my mind, **why should I use any framework as dagger to handle this, if I can handle this pattern by myself, once it's not thaaat complicated?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Should I use the same object from api to store in local database?**

It can really depend on how good your API object is. You should rather base your local database object on what it really mean in a logical way and if your endpoint is well done it could be the same. The important part in your architecture is to isolate your logic parts from your I/O parts (UI, database, API) so if you want to redesign your UI, change the Webservice you use it will not be too painful.

**So I misunderstood the concepts or it make sense?**

I am not that familiar with MVVM so I can not really answer that question. But for me the important is not to follow "by the book" one pattern or another but rather to adapt your architecture from what you like from each. I currently try do to so with the [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html). You can take a look at all the concepts Uncle Bob speak about in this article about making code cleaner and more maintainable.

**why should I use any framework as dagger to handle this, if I can handle this pattern by myself, once it's not thaaat complicated?**

You don't have to use dagger if you're not familiar with it. But if your project start to grow and you start to be a team of 2, 3, 5... working on it, a framework as dagger can help you keeping a common standard about how you make your dependency injection and then making the code more coherent. Dagger also provide some tools as scopes that can save you some time if you're familiar with it.